# Pure Javascript array, get values using several html buttons that show array

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to create, using pure JavaScript and HTML, an array of hardcoded albums, each album has a `title`, `category`, `artist`, `tracks[]`. Now where I am stuck is trying to display my array `onclick` of a button and displayed differently dependent on which button is pushed. I have three buttons:

1. Get All Albums
2. Get All Albums By Artist
3. Get All By Category.

When I click on All I get all Albums by name in a bulleted list. By Artist I get all Albums only By Artist. Here is my code. I am working with external JavaScript files.   Any help is greatly appreciated, But please no JQuery I want to do this in pure javascript.

[Here is a jsbin of what i have so far](http://jsbin.com/ufanep/121/edit)

[here](http://jsbin.com/ufanep/121/edit)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if you provide a link to jsFiddle and/or jsBin please try to also include the relevant code here.

Comment: The worst offender is to do a document.write after page load. Fill a container's innerHTML instead

Comment: @mplungjan or build everything in DOM methods such as `createElement`, etc.

Comment: @Paul S. are there any good examples I can look at? I have gotten buttons to work on a very generic level w/o the tracks[] using inner js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help

```
<button id="b1" type="button">Get All Albums</button>
<button id="b2" type="button">Get All Albums By Artist</button>
<button id="b3" type="button">Get All By Category</button>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Tracks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="albums"></tbody>
</table>

var b1 = document.getElementById("b1"),
    b2 = document.getElementById("b2"),
    b3 = document.getElementById("b3"),
    results = document.getElementById("albums"),
    albums = [];

function compareTitle(a, b) {
    if (a.title < b.title) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.title > b.title) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

function compareArtist(a, b) {
    if (a.artist < b.artist) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.artist > b.artist) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

function compareCategory(a, b) {
    if (a.category < b.category) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.category > b.category) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

function addAlbum(title, category, artist, tracks) {
    var album = {
        "title": title,
            "category": category,
            "artist": artist,
            "tracks": tracks
    };

    albums.push(album);
}

addAlbum("d", "z", "s", [1, 2, 3]);
addAlbum("c", "y", "s", [1, 2, 3]);
addAlbum("b", "x", "t", [1, 2, 3]);
addAlbum("a", "x", "u", [1, 2, 3]);

function displayAll() {
    results.innerHTML = "";
    albums.sort(compareTitle);

    albums.forEach(function (album) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr"),
            td1 = document.createElement("td"),
            td2 = document.createElement("td"),
            td3 = document.createElement("td"),
            td4 = document.createElement("td");

        td1.textContent = album.title;
        td2.textContent = album.category;
        td3.textContent = album.artist;
        td4.textContent = album.tracks.toString();

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        results.appendChild(tr);
    });
}

function displayArtist() {
    results.innerHTML = "";
    albums.sort(compareArtist);

    albums.forEach(function (album) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr"),
            td1 = document.createElement("td"),
            td2 = document.createElement("td"),
            td3 = document.createElement("td"),
            td4 = document.createElement("td");

        td1.textContent = album.title;
        td2.textContent = album.category;
        td3.textContent = album.artist;
        td4.textContent = album.tracks.toString();

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        results.appendChild(tr);
    });
}

function displayCategory() {
    results.innerHTML = "";
    albums.sort(compareCategory);

    albums.forEach(function (album) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr"),
            td1 = document.createElement("td"),
            td2 = document.createElement("td"),
            td3 = document.createElement("td"),
            td4 = document.createElement("td");

        td1.textContent = album.title;
        td2.textContent = album.category;
        td3.textContent = album.artist;
        td4.textContent = album.tracks.toString();

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        results.appendChild(tr);
    });
}

b1.addEventListener("click", displayAll, false);
b2.addEventListener("click", displayArtist, false);
b3.addEventListener("click", displayCategory, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FfbVp/)

Comment: YESSS!!! How awesome are you! Wow! Thank you so much for organizing in a way that i can understand too. I am sure there are shortcuts to it. But I really want to grasp what i am doing and this is EXACTLY what I have been trying to find. Thank You x infinity! Gotta love the foreach!

Comment: Oh yes, there is far more code than is necessary (repeated), but the main thing was to give you something to work with.

Comment: i cant thank you enough. With repetition comes perfection. I want to learn the long way first, then discover shortcuts on my own. You have definitely given me something I can work with and understand... I will say it again. You are sofa king awesome!!